# Возможность переноса вопросов на Русский Язык

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, перенос-вопросов

Предлагаю добавить возможность переносить вопросы на [Русский Язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/).

Например, [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729183/227016), как мне кажется, можно было бы туда перенести.

Comment: А принимающая сторона будет рада подобным вопросам?

Comment: @Arhad, ну, предполагается использование только для вопросов, которые точно подходят для Русского Языка. Мне кажется что этот вопрос подходит, нет?

Comment: Ну, модераторы (или заведующий сообществом) уже и так могут переносить тот или иной вопрос при желании, так что, думаю, хватило бы и обращения к ним в чате.

Comment: Вопрос перенесен.

Comment: @Nofate, спасибо!

Comment: @nick что [завершено]? Возможности переноса вопросов нет на рус.яз. Пишите, пожалуйста, ответ, когда ставите красную метку.

Comment: @alexolut Завершен перенос, вероятно!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky но ведь предложение об общей возможности, а не одном единичном случае.

Comment: @alexolut Ага, я понял! И ответил на него.

Answer (score 4):

В выпадающем меню содержатся наиболее часто употребляемые причины закрытия и наиболее релевантные сайты для переноса вопросов. Субъективно, вопросы, предназначенные для сайта Русский язык, на Stack Overflow на русском не появляются так часто, чтобы расширять меню закрытия.

Пожалуйста, используйте тревогу «требует внимания модератора», где укажите, что вопрос следует перенести.