# Почему в причине закрытия "Не соответствие тематике сообщества" только одна Мета?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, перенос-вопросов

Есть у нас замечательная причина закрытия вопроса

> В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса.

Проблема в том, что из всех сайтов сети SE там присутствует только Мета ruSO.

Это так и задумывалось? Или может стоит добавить остальные сайты сети?

Вот из последнего [Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли в данном предложении запятая?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/983902/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F)

Вопрос должен быть на https://rus.stackexchange.com/ но закрыть его с этой причиной нельзя

Comment: Модераторы могут переносить на любые сайты сети. Просто оставьте тревогу с указанием нужного сайта.

Comment: @PashaPash так и сделал. Если добавлять остальные сайты не планируется, может вообще стоит убрать этот пункт закрытия?

Comment: Пусть будет. Чаще всего промахиваются именно в сторону меты. rus.stackexchange.com - это исключение.

Comment: @PashaPash Зато enSo часто нужен

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, против переноса на enSO высказались модераторы enSO :)

Comment: И дополнительный дубликат: [Возможность переноса вопросов на Русский Язык](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6071/186999)

Comment: enSO может и нужен. Но нужны ли наши вопросы enSO? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372553/why-do-homework-dump-questions-get-migrated

Comment: @Grundy это не дубликат, т.к. тут скорее **обсуждение расширения списка сайтов для переноса**, а не перенос англ.вопросов или механизм переноса в целом.

Comment: @Kromster, там по сути тоже было обсуждение. Поэтому я два вопроса и указал.  Оба они полностью покрывают текущий вопрос. Результат обсуждения будет таким же.

Comment: @Grundy было бы все же лучше этот вопрос дистанцировать - т.к. изменение просится минимальное и разумное (см. мой ответ)

Comment: @Kromster, не просится, потому что с топ-5 те же проблемы что и с enSO - они как минимум не русскоязычные и им хватает плохих вопросов, которые напрямую задаются. Про rusSO есть ответ в связанном вопросе.

Comment: @Grundy про русскоязычность вы правы, хороший аргумент - запостите это как ответ?

Answer (score 3):

По идее там должны располагаться, например, топ5 сайтов на которые делается перенос. У администрации такая статистика наверняка есть.

Почему, например, топ5? - это не слишком мало, как сейчас всего 1, и не слишком много, чтобы пришлось скролить и искать по фильтрам.

По ощущениям, там точно окажется Мета и enSO.